# execvp() with grep that has quotation marks

Tags: c, shell, grep, execvp, quotation-marks

I did 'grep' in my own little shell.
Other commands, like 'ls -al', 'pwd' ..etc, is working.
But When I put 'grep', there was some problems.

```
char* f_grep[] = {"grep", "-n", "a", "a.txt", NULL};
char* s_grep[] = {"grep", "-n", "'a'", "a.txt", NULL};
```

`execvp(f_grep[0], f_grep); // This works.`

```
execvp(s_grep[0], s_grep); // This doesn't work.
```

I was wondering why I cannot use quotation marks with grep in execvp().

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't work"? It works just fine -- it finds the three-character string `'a'`, just like it's supposed to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks !! Now I can understand what i did wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the shell removes one level of quotes from the command line arguments. So if you type,

```
grep -n 'a' a.txt
```

that's no different than

```
grep -n a a.txt
```

because the shell will remove the quotes.

However, when you pass a string with quotes to `execvp`, the quotes will not be removed. Which means that the example with `s_grep` is the same as typing

```
grep -n "'a'" a.txt
```

The shell will remove the double quotes, and leave the single quotes, which is what's happening with `execvp`.

---

If you want to experiment with this, you'll need two programs. The first program (called "showme") just echoes its command line arguments:

```
// showme.c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

The second program calls `execvp` with some arguments for "showme":

```
int main(void)
{
    char *args[] = { "./showme", "a", "'b'", NULL };
    execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

The output:

```
0: ./showme
1: a
2: 'b'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I do fully understand what you say. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason if this answer solved the problem, consider ticking the green checkbox beside the answer.

Comment: @bishop Thanks. This is my first question, so i didn't know about it. Have a nice day !!